# Encryption algorithm/hardware that can sign/verify natural time?

Tags: algorithm, encryption

So here is my stupid quesion:

PGP/GPGP can used to sign text, others use public key to verify them.

Let's say, asymmetric cryptographic algorithm deal with space.

Are there any algorithm that can deal with *time*?

E.g. Sign a document at 2011-10-10 10:10:10, others can verify this document is really, truely signed at 2011-10-10 10-10-10.

I know there are maybe solutions based on a common trusted time source, but is it possible that a **pure** algorithm solution exists?

Or perhaps some amazing dedicated piece of hardware can do this? (E.g. half-life of certain well-known material, etc.)

Comment: Don't you think these results can be easily 'faked' by building a 'clone' of that 'hardware'? (Or better: recording the times that the hardware 'returns'. If you can't record the times, how would someone be able to *verify* that the 'times' are correct? Actually, this doesn't make much sense in the first place since time is... well, you know.)

Comment: @muntoo You could have the device sign its output with a private key securely stored inside the device. The device is then the trusted third party I described in my answer, of course. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is out of the scope of a cryptographic algorithm, because there's no such thing as absolute time (and if there were, there's no way to measure it from inside a computer). What you're asking for requires a trusted third party - the wikipedia article on [Trusted Timestamping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) describes this. Another approach is one similar to that used in bitcoin, where distributed agreement is created on a sequence of events; the order of events is decided by the order in which they became part of the consensus. This provides a relative measure of time as a sequence of events, not a wallclock time.

Comment: > This provides a relative measure of time as a sequence of events
  
So can we record the sequence of atomic clock cycle or a quantum state?

Comment: @est No, you can record events based on when they happened relative to other events.

Answer (score 2):

OpenPGP signs data (not text), as does any other signing mechanism. Data has no special meaning besides the one humans put into it. "3.1415926" can be treated as value of Pi expressed in decimals or as a randomizer salt or as a password to one's home computer, you choose.

Consequently, time is just some large number, relative to starting point agreed by people (eg. 30 Dec 1899 in OLE time). You can sign time as you would sign any other data. The question is where you get the value. As Nick Johnson pointed, you need a trusted time source. This can be some NTP server (then you need to sign the value) or some TSP server (it produces signed values if you trust it).

In general, you can read [RFC 3161](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161) about Timestamping protocol which relies on trusted third parties. While there exist other schemes and they are great, TSP protocol described in RFC 3161 became the most widely used approach nowadays.